# How to remove table padding in my case

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a html table and encounter an issue here.

I was hoping to specify one particular row to have no padding with CSS.

html

```
<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>$810</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>$80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>$810</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

css

```
table, th, td {
    border:solid 1px red;
}

table {
     border-collapse: inherit;
     border-spacing: 5px;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3rL9dryp/1/

In jsFiddle, all rows in table has padding to upper rows. I want to keep the padding for each row but need to remove top padding to upper row for a single row (for example, third row). Is this doable?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can create a class that contains the desired padding. Then add that class to the <td>'s where you'd like the padding added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS3 pseudo-selector `:nth-child`:

```
table tr:nth-child(3) td {
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of the code working. I added `padding-top:100px` to emphasize the difference.
http://jsfiddle.net/m704mxz6/1/

Change it to `padding-top:0px;` to achieve your goal.

Comment: Hi Nick, you'd be better off posting the HTML and CSS as part of your question as inline code (like @BonJon did) so that (a) people on restricted networks can see your answer, (b) the answer is immediately visible for comparison to the question, and (c) if the site goes down, the code is still there.